# in tensorflow, how to initialize part of variables

Tags: variables, tensorflow, initialization

I want to initialize a list of variable and I have define them as a list named 'block_var'. I want to use the truncated normal method to initialize them.

```
block_var = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' in v.name]
init_block = tf.variables_initializer(var_list = block_var)
```

then what should I do?
I have tried

```
for v in block_var:
    v.initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer()
```

I also tried

```
init_block = tf.truncated_normal_initializer()
```

both field.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You need to pass the initializer argument for `get_variable` like

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ref0 = tf.get_variable('block0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))
ref1 = tf.get_variable('block1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))
ref2 = tf.get_variable('block2', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))

ref4 = tf.get_variable('foo0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))
ref5 = tf.get_variable('foo1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))

block_vars = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' in v.name]
block_vars_complement = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' not in v.name]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=block_vars))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref0, ref1, ref2])), 'should be ~ 40')

    try:
        print(np.mean(sess.run([ref4])))
    except Exception as e:
        print('[INFO] failed as expected with message %s' % e)

    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=block_vars_complement))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref4, ref5])), 'should be ~ 10')
```

### Solution 2

If you do not want to pass the `initializer` to each `get_variable` you could use a custom getter like

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def my_getter(getter, name, shape, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'block' not in name:
        return getter(name=name, shape=shape, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        kwargs['initializer'] = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40)
        return getter(name=name, shape=shape, *args, **kwargs)

with tf.variable_scope("some_scopename", custom_getter=my_getter):
    ref0 = tf.get_variable('block0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))
    ref1 = tf.get_variable('block1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))
    ref2 = tf.get_variable('block2', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))

    ref4 = tf.get_variable('foo0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))
    ref5 = tf.get_variable('foo1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))

block_vars = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' in v.name]
block_vars_complement = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' not in v.name]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=block_vars))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref0, ref1, ref2])), 'should be ~ 40')

    try:
        print(np.mean(sess.run([ref4])))
    except Exception as e:
        print('[INFO] failed as expected with message %s' % e)

    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=block_vars_complement))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref4, ref5])), 'should be ~ 10')
```

### Solution 3

[`tf.truncated_normal_initializer`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/truncated_normal_initializer) or other initializers are just operations on its own. Hence, these can be applied in a loop to all variables from a collection and such a grouped update can be finally applied (see `initialize_collection`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ref0 = tf.get_variable('block0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))
ref1 = tf.get_variable('block1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))
ref2 = tf.get_variable('block2', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=40))

ref4 = tf.get_variable('foo0', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))
ref5 = tf.get_variable('foo1', [2], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10))

block_vars = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' in v.name]
block_vars_complement = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'block' not in v.name]


def initialize_collection(collection, initializer):
    ops = []
    for v in collection:
        ops.append(v.assign(initializer(shape=v.shape)))
    return tf.group(ops)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=block_vars))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref0, ref1, ref2])), 'should be ~ 40')

    sess.run(initialize_collection(block_vars, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=-40, stddev=0.01)))
    print(np.mean(sess.run([ref0, ref1, ref2])), 'should be ~ -40')
```

Answer (score -1):

Update : As mentioned in the comments my earlier code had bugs. It created new variables. So I have made improvements and now I use assert to check.

It could be like this.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.variable_scope("reuse"):
    x = tf.get_variable('x', [5, 5])
    y = tf.get_variable('y', [5, 5])

block_var = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]

def initialize( name, shape ):
    with tf.variable_scope("reuse",reuse=True):
        x = tf.get_variable(name.split(':')[0][-1],  shape = shape, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        x.initializer.run()
        print (x.eval())


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    vars = sess.run(block_var)
    for name,shape in zip(block_var,vars):
        initialize( name, shape.shape )
    assert (len(tf.global_variables()) == 2), "Variables are not reused"
```

Comment: Adding `print(len(tf.global_variables()))` reveals your are creating new variables. Hence any operation depending on previous vars will not be affected.

Comment: I planned to test it like that but didn't. Mine is a simpler attempt to understand and answer.

Comment: But it might not helpful to post some code with flaws, when people tend to copy 'nd paste answers from SO.